# Model driven development in Netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

Is there anyway I can model my project and then generate source from that model in Netbeans 8. Because from the discussions in the net I have been able to conclude that Netbeans has discontinued a well used UML plugin.

Comment: Java web application

Comment: Jsp, html will be my Front. Struts and hibernate will be my backend